# Passing variables into methods

Tags: java

I have a program that is asking for a name of an insured person. I am making a method called promptInsuredName and want to know the best way to pass those variables into the method.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class BurtonLavato002PA2 {

    String message = "", coverage = "";
    double payout = 0.0, deductible = 0.0;
    boolean repeat;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char cont = ' ', correct = ' ', another = ' ';
        String insured = " ";
        double homeInsVal = ' ', richter = ' ';
        Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();


        System.out.println("MUTUALLY ACCIDENTAL, INC.");
        System.out.printf("%nDo you want an analysis of earthquake coverage for your property? Enter 'Y' or 'N':  ");
        cont = input.next().charAt(0);
        input.nextLine();

        while(cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y'){
            promptInsuredName(insured, input);

            

            }// END OF WHILE


        }// END OF MAIN

    static String promptInsuredName(String insured, Scanner input) {
        System.out.printf("%nMUTUALLY ACCIDENTAL, INC.");    //Header for the prompt
        System.out.printf("%nEarthquake Coverage Analyzer");

        System.out.printf("%n%nPlease enter your name:  ");
        insured = input.nextLine(); // Take input under the Scanner stdin to read insured name.
        return insured;
    } // END OF promptInsuredName


    }// END OF CLASS
```

Insured and scanner input are passed into the promptInsuredName method

Comment: You can't pass variables into the method the way you want, only return output out.

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: When posting here, try to strip away as much extraneous code as possible, to focus on your core issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `Scanner` to your method. In general we need to make our methods as agnostic to the input as possible, yet, if you pass `Scanner`, then you assume that a `Scanner` is being used. Instead, declare your method as

```
static String promptInsuredName(String insured, String input) {
```

and pass the result of `input.nextLine()` to it. This way your method will work even if the input is not generated by `Scanner` and CLI. In general, you need to separate the input from its parsing.